# Cannot put object to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, zend-framework, bucket

I'm fighting with it for the last couple of days and I'm hopeless.

I use Zend S3 lib to access my S3 via IAM account.
I'm able to list and create my buckets, but I cannot put any object nor read info ($s3->getInfo()) of a sample file I uploaded via console.
I set to my IAM account to full access: AmazonS3FullAccess, also added my own:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetAccessPoint",
            "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:ListJobs",
            "s3:CreateJob",
            "s3:HeadBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "arn:aws:s3:*:*:accesspoint/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:*:*:job/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
    }
]
```

}

This is my PHP code:

```
    $amazonKey = AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
    $amazonSecret = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

    $s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($amazonKey, $amazonSecret);

    //Avaliable buckets this code works:
    $this->view->content.="-----------Avaliable buckets:-------------<br>";
    foreach($s3->getBuckets() as $bucket)

     $this->view->content.=$bucket."<br>";

      //this doesn't work
     $amazonBucket='map-markers';
     $object=$amazonBucket."/myobject";

    $result=$s3->putObject($object, "somedata");

    if ($result===false) $this->view->content.="putObject: '.$object.' FAIL!";
    else
    $this->view->content.="putObject: ".print_r($result)."<br>";
```

Also I tried C++ builder lib for AWS TAmazonStorageService: `

```
if (s3->UploadObject(BUCKET_NAME,OBJ_NAME,AnsiString("test").BytesOf()),true,0, amzbaPrivate, amzrNotSpecified, ResponseInfo) {

       TVarRec args[1] = {ResponseInfo->StatusMessage};
       Console("UploadObject:Upload to "+AnsiString(BUCKET_NAME)+" "+OBJ_NAME+" OK!");
     }

     else
     {
          TVarRec args[1] = {ResponseInfo->StatusMessage};
          Console(Format(AnsiString("UploadObject Failure! %s"), args, 0));

     }
```

S3->UploadObject returns true along with  "HTTP 200" in ResponseInfo but the object is not created.
Bucket permissions are like this :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "S3Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::map-markers/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::map-markers"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Additionally I unblocked all public access to the bucket.

I have no Idea what else could I do?

best regards
Tom

`

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is related to permissions? Is there a specific error message coming back? You could test the permissions by using the AWS CLI to upload the file using the same IAM User. If that works, then the error is something else to do with your code, not the permissions.

Comment: That's exactly what makes me crazy! As you see the above PHP and C++ code is simple, there is no room to mess up! If $s3->getBuckets() works  $s3->putObject($object, "somedata"); should work too! Or there is some magic to putting objects that  I don't know about?

Comment: Have you considered using the official [AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html) rather than zend?

Comment: Yes I did but as both the C++ and Zend PHP code gave same results I thought the problem were my S3 settings. I'll give it a try and see.Thanks.